# Android Studio error, multiple dex files

Tags: android, gradle, dex

I am unable to build my project, it is returning me one error. There are no errors in the files themselves, only upon a build.

This is the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\UploadToServer\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\UploadToServer\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I have read on a few other post that it could be multiples of the same jar files in the libs folder but currently my folder is empty, I am not to sure what the issue is, I would appreciate if someone could help.

Here is my module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jay.uploadtoserver"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r6'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your jar files does not compile. You should go into your `build.gradle` file in your project, and look in your dependencies, if your just import some jar files, you could try to remove them, and add one at a time, to see which one of them makes the error.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:18.0.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r6`'. AppCompat already has this library